# iOS React Native app crashes NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

Tags: ios, react-native

I had a warning saying that I was missing the key 'NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription' from my info.plist at my next app submission after upgrading to Xcode 8.

So I added the key and a valid string description, tested my app on a local device and it allows me to access my camera. Ps. I'm using the following React Native library - https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker

However when I publish the app to TestFlight, the warning no longer displays, but when I run the function to access the camera my app crashes and exits. I have allowed there app to access my camera too.

Would there be any other reason for this?

Comment: Realised the photo library states that I need to add 'NSCameraUsageDescription' to the plist too, so I hope this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'NSCameraUsageDescription' to plist.info fixed my issue.